# Processing image and find outer edge. Find an algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I have problem with one from steps which i have to do. Most important problem.
I have an image, for example:
[image]

The second step's to select part of image:
[image]

Ok. If i have this image in cache, which selected area:

[image]

Early steps i have done. Problem is with the last step, which task is to select only (exactly outer) border area. Here's example how it should looks:

[image]

My ask's to what algorithm or steps i have to do for the last effect. It's feasible for any images?
My prefered language's C#/C/JS but if somebody know the knowledge about solution it will be nice!
I had find some algorithm for detect edge, but not for outer edge.

Comment: You can most probably follow the approach from this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11819/help-find-a-bright-object-on-mars). I.e. make a Gaussian prob model of the background.

Comment: Also, dsp.stackexchange.com is a better place for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the following:

- pick some random 10 pixels from borders of selection (it is important that those are borders)
- get average rgb of those pixels
- get MAX = max color distance between pixels
- perform white flood fill with tolerance = k*MAX, starting from one of edge pixels

this way you should be able to flood fill only the gray background in selection

Comment: Thanks you for answer, but if i would have other background, f.e: some flowers or other..then this algorithm can help me too?

Comment: No, this will help only in the case when your background color distribution is pretty flat. In case of complex background this would not help.